# Is there a way to automatically generate \bibitem entries from a bibtex file?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have a LaTeX document with bibliography done using bibtex (so I have a .bib file). However, looks like my current collaborator is not familiar with bibtex and doesn't want to get familiar (as he is considerably more senior I can't really force him to anything).

Is there an automated way to generate `\bibitem` entries from my bibtex file, so that I could just copy these into the version I will send to my collaborator?

Comment: Related questions: [Handling bibtex with collaborators](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3673/215) [Getting references out of auxiliary files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6512/215)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `\bibitem`s are in the `.bbl` file generated by BibTeX. Just run it once and copy them from this file.

If required you can use `\nocite{*}` in your document to force the citation of all entries of the `.bib` file.