# How do I truncate the author list and substitute et al.?

Tags: bibtex, natbib, author-number

Can someone please tell me if there is a way to truncate more than 2 authors for a publication and substitute it by `et al.` instead? I am using BibTeX.

Comment: Near-duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5662/bibtex-automatic-replacement-of-4-authors-with-et-al

Comment: This answer helped me do what I needed to do: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26582/120014

Comment: Check this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/482291/113143

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use the package natbib it is very easy:

```
  \citet{jon90}         -->     Jones et al. (1990)
  \citet[chap. 2]{jon90}        -->     Jones et al. (1990, chap. 2)
  \citep{jon90}         -->     (Jones et al., 1990)
  \citep[chap. 2]{jon90}        -->     (Jones et al., 1990, chap. 2)
```

see the full info in this excellent quick how to:

http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php

example:

```
@article{Sillimanetal1995,
title = "Quantifying downflow through creek sediments using temperature time series: one-dimensional solution incorporating measured surface temperature.",
journal = "Journal of Hydrology",
volume = "167",
number = "1-4",
pages = "99 - 119",
year = "1995",
note = "",
issn = "0022-1694",
doi = "DOI: 10.1016/0022-1694(94)02613-G",
author = "Stephen E. Silliman and Jose Ramirez and Raye L. McCabe"
}
```

will be cited as:

```
Silliman et al. (1995)
```

if you use:
    \citet{sillimanetal1995}

if you   want the full list of authors you do:

```
\citet*{sillimanetal1995}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand perfectly on how to limit the number of authors to 2 though. I will try reading the documentation again.

Comment: you don't need to limit anything. Once you have in your bibtext more than 2 authors separated with the keyword "and" natbib will take care of things properly. I edited my code above to comply.

Comment: Actually, I am new to the latex typesetting system. I just checked my directory and it does not seem to have a bst file although it has a bbl file and a cls file.

Comment: if you don't have a bst file, you can download from a publisher website or just use natbib's default.

Comment: the link i pasted here has 3 examples of bst file, go through the link and find them please. If you are new to latex, i highly recommend slowly reading through wikibooks excellent latex book

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much for helping me out on this. I will go through these tonight.