# Automatically reduce long authors list

Tags: bibtex

I've found this topic which is very near to my problem:
[BibTex: How can I automatically reduce long author lists to "xxx et al."?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26575/bibtex-how-can-i-automatically-reduce-long-author-lists-to-xxx-et-al)
I'd like to use `natdin` though. Can anyone help me with the code?

Comment: Hi Jan - I edited your post. Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts, or sign our names (it appears at the bottom right of every post). While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: What's `natdin`?

Comment: @egreg: [`natdin.bst`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/german/din1505), I presume.

Comment: `natdin.bst` is to be used with `natbib`. Would you please present an example of what you're doing?

Answer (score 3):

Use the same solution as in the answer you reference.  Just copy the file `natdin.bst` (in my system it is in `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/din1505/natdin.bst`, check yours!) to the file `mynatdin.bst`, add the code suggested by Mico and say `\bibliographystyle{mynatdin}`.

Note that this will use German *u. a.* instead of Latin *et. al.* for the omitted authors - but this is probably what you want.

Comment: Maybe I'm too stupid for UPN but in the end I was using biblatex with \printbibliography[maxnames=3]. Easy & straight forward. Using ngerman, the only thing I had to add was: \DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\ al\adddot}} in order to get "et al." instead of "u. a.".