# maximum number of authors

Tags: bibliographies

1. I want to write Boehler et.al. (2003) but I 'm getting names of all
   authors. How can I fix maximum number of authos with
2. How can I get 30 Sept. **–** 4 Oct. Currenty , I ' getting 30 Sept.
   4 Oct

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\begin{document}
Some text \citet{BoehlerW2003}.
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{Mybiblo}% Change this to use a different bibliography database file.
\end{document}
```

Mybiblo.bib

```
@CONFERENCE{BoehlerW2003,
  author = {W. Boehler and  Vicent M. Bordas and  A. Marbs},
  title = {Investigating laser scanner accuracy},
  booktitle = {CIPA Symposium at Antalya, Turkey, 30 Sept. – 4 Oct},
  year = {2003},
  owner = {S.S},
  timestamp = {2013.06.02}
}
```

Comment: The missing dash is due to the fact that you don't enable UTF-8; use `--` instead of `–` (U+2013).

Answer (score 2):

you could use the `natbib` package (available [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib)), set it  `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`.

If you want to change the amount of authors' name to appear (I think the default is two), you can set so by looking into the `natbib` [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf)

Some extra references:

[BibTeX: How can I automatically reduce long author lists to "xxx et al."?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26575/bibtex-how-can-i-automatically-reduce-long-author-lists-to-xxx-et-al/26578#26578)

Comment: I believe the number of authors can't be controlled by `natbib`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel yeap, I think the same.  That's why I'm directing the OP to the natbib package documentation :) .   I just can't remmeber what was the command for maximum authors' names.

Comment: I had a mistake in my first comment. I meant "can't", Sorry

Comment: @MarcoDaniel So maybe twitching with the .bst file, as described in the provided related question?

Comment: I don't think this is the correct answer, check mine, Natbib has a command for Foo et al.

Comment: If you look into `apacite.bst` you will find the function `format.6.authors` which controls the output. If you want to reduce the number you have to hack this function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want Boehler et al. (2003), use the following:

```
\citeauthor{BoehlerW2003}\ \citeyearpar{BoehlerW2003}
```

For more commands, check the [LaTeX Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Natbib).