# Remove page numbers and conference title

Tags: bibtex

Is there a way to modify the bst file to format the references such that the page numbers and the conference titles are removed ?

For example, like this reference:

> V. Raykar et al. “Supervised learning from multiple experts: Whom to
>   trust when everyone lies a bit”. In: ICML (2009).

I was able to reduce long author list to et al by modifying the bst file following this post: [BibTeX: How can I automatically reduce long author lists to "xxx et al."?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26575/bibtex-how-can-i-automatically-reduce-long-author-lists-to-xxx-et-al).

Comment: Is there a particular bst file that you want to modify?

Comment: I want to modify the unsrt.bst

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a copy of [`unsrt.bst`](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/biblio/bibtex/base/unsrt.bst) with a different name. To ignore page numbers, find the function `format.pages` and change it to

```
FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ ""
}
```

To ignore the `booktitle` one can remove the line

```
format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
```

from the functions `incollection` and `inproceedings`. For a tutorial on BibTeX including a discussion of the `.bst` file see [Tame the BeaST](http://tug.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf).