# Bibliography style?

Tags: bibliographies

I'm looking for the bibliography style where "references should be numbered in order of citation and cited in the text by numbers in square brackets. They should be listed in the reference list in the form prescribed in the Uniform Requirements (giving the names and initials of all authors, unless there are more than six, when the first three should be given, followed by et al.)". Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a bibliography style such as `unsrt`. For a posting that discusses how one might modify `unsrt.bst` so that just the first few authors of a bibliographic entry are shown, see [BibTeX: How can I automatically reduce long author lists to “xxx et al.”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26575/5001).

Comment: Or use `biblatex` and `biber`?

Comment: Your requirements are both very specific and not likely to be fully implemented by any of the "standard" bibliography styles. If you want to stick with BibTeX, I suggest you acquaint yourself with the [custom-bib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) package and its `makebst` utility. This utility, which can be run by typing `latex makebst` at a command prompt, lets users create custom styles from scratch. It's entirely menu-driven, i.e., you'll get a lot of questions and multiple-choice type answers. Follow the prompts and create yourself a custom `.bst` file.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest, like @cfr, using `biblatex` and `biber`. You should write, e.g.:

```
...........................
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric,first inits,maxnames=6,minnames=3]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{your_bibliofile.bib}
............................
\begin{document}
.....................
\printbibliography
```

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for pointing the typo. Corrected.

Comment: @cfr I use BibTex (JabRef).