# Displaying first author's name in a bibliographic entry in the form: Surname, Initials and co-authors in the form: Initials, Surname

Tags: bibtex

I would like to format my references according to the following specifications:

> Author: Surname, Initials, Co-authors: Initials, Surname

I am using `natbib`, `abbrvnat` for bibliography style and I guess I have to edit the `.bst` file (`FUNCTION {format.names}`).

I would appreciate if someone could help me with this or recommend something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the desired ordering of authors' first and last names, I suggest you do the following:

- Find the file `abbrvnat.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and name the copy, say, `myabbrvnat.bst`. (Don't edit a file from the TeX distribution directly.
- Open the file `myabbrvnat.bst` in a text editor; the editor you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- Find the function `format.names` in the file. (In my copy of the file, this function starts on line 216. Delete all 27 or so lines of function; the last line will contain just a right curly brace, `}`.
- Insert the following code chunk in the place of the deleted function:

  ```
  FUNCTION {format.names}
  { duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
    's :=
    "" 't :=
    #1 'nameptr :=
    s num.names$ 'numnames :=
    numnames 'namesleft :=
      { namesleft #0 > }
      { s nameptr
        duplicate$ #1 >
          { "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" }
          { "{vv~}{ll}{, f.}{, jj}" }
        if$
        format.name$
        't :=
        nameptr #1 >
          {
            namesleft #1 >
              { ", " * t * }
              {
                s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                  { 't := }
                  { pop$ }
                if$
                "," *
                t "others" =
                  { " et~al." * }
                  { " " * t * }
                if$
              }
            if$
          }
          't
        if$
        nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
        namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
      }
    while$
    } if$
  }
  ```

  Do note that I've interpreted your specification as indicating that there should be no "and" connector word before the final author in the author list.
- Save the file `myabbrvnat.bst`, either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a folder that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter method, be sure to udpate the filename database of your TeX distribution appropriately.
- Start using the new bibliography style by replacing the instruction `\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}` with `\bibliographystyle{myabbrvnat}`. Be sure to run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Here's an example file:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{myabbrvnat}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@article{abc,
  author    = "Anna Anderson and Brenda Branson and Carla Carlson",
  title     = "Random thoughts",
  journal   = "Circularity Today",
  year      = 3001,
  volume    = 1,
  number    = 1,
  pages     = "1-100",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Mico, many thanks for your help. It works fine. I just added an and at ' { " " * t * } ' and now is ' { " and " * t * } ' in order to have the and before the last author. At last, do you know how I can specify the 'et al.' after a certain number of authors? Thanks a lot, Giorgos.

Comment: @gioR - Glad you found my answer useful. :-) On your follow-up question: Do you want to truncate the list of authors in the citation callout or in the bib entries?

Comment: I would like to truncate the list of authors in the citation callout. Giorgos

Comment: If you load the `natbib` citation management package, the styles `abbrvnat` and `myabbrvnat` will automatically truncate the citation callout to FirstAuthor et al for entries with three or more authors.

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work. When I compile my manuscript it prints all the authors in the references list. In particular, I would like to print 'et al.' after the 6th author. Giorgos

Comment: @gioR - So you do want truncation of the list of authors in the references rather than in the citations. For instructions on how to truncate the list of authors in a bib entry, see the answers to the posting [BibTeX: How can I automatically reduce long author lists to "xxx et al."?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26575/5001) The accepted answer works on the `unsrt` style, but the instructions apply to other styles as well, including `abbrv` and `abbrvnat`.

Comment: You are right, it's my fault. I meant the bib entries. I saw the post you recommended and now I have what I want. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @Mico This is alsomost right for a question I got, but bibtex is complaining about a missing definition for `bibinfo.check`, not sure if the current `abbrevnat.bst` is newer than the version this question is made for. Any suggestions?

Comment: @daleif - It's been a while since I wrote this answer, and I can't quite remember what all I did. (I probably cribbed much of the code from a test run of the `makebst` utility.) Let me get back to you later today with a full answer. In the meantime, simply deleting the lines (strings) `'bibinfo :=` and `bibinfo bibinfo.check` should get you going -- assuming all author names are well-formed. I suspect the `bibinfo.check` function is there to issue an alert if one or more names are not well formed. I need to figure out what a suitable version of the function `bibinfo.check` should look like.

Comment: @daleif - I decided to make the temporary fix "official", i.e., to simply drop all uses of `bibinfo` and `bibinfo.check` in the replacement code.