# Is there any bibliography style can give me more brief author text?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

My problem now is in my thesis on the `References` part some references it take to much lines because i refer some papers from CERN, RHIC (so much authors per paper may be more that twenty, that too much) can you suggest me to some bibliography style that can make

> I. Arsene and I.G. Bearden and D. Beavis and C. Besliu and B. Budick
>   and H. Bøggild and C. Chasman and C.H. Christensen and P. Christiansen
>   and J. Cibor and R. Debbe and E. Enger and J.J. Gaardhøje and M.
>   Germinario and O. Hansen and A. Holm and A.K. Holme and K. Hagel and
>   H. Ito and E. Jakobsen and A. Jipa and F. Jundt and J.I. Jørdre and
>   C.E. Jørgensen and R. Karabowicz and E.J. Kim and T. Kozik and T.M.
>   Larsen and J.H. Lee and Y.K. Lee and S. Lindahl and G. Løvhøiden and
>   Z. Majka and A. Makeev and M. Mikelsen and M.J. Murray and J. Natowitz
>   and B. Neumann and B.S. Nielsen and D. Ouerdane and R. Płaneta and F.
>   Rami and C. Ristea and O. Ristea and D. Röhrich and B.H. Samset and D.
>   Sandberg and S.J. Sanders and R.A. Scheetz and P. Staszel and T.S.
>   Tveter and F. Videbæk and R. Wada and Z. Yin and I.S. Zgura

might be to

> I. Arsene and I.G. Bearden and D. Beavis and C. Besliu et al.

on my references page?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you checked out the posting [BibTeX: How can I automatically reduce long author lists to "xxx et al."?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26575/5001). The answer given there applies to the `unsrt` style, but it's easily adapted to the `plain` style.

Comment: Thank you so much. And sorry for my duplicated problem. I think i'd searched already but may be miss something.

Comment: No apologies needed for posting something that may turn out to be a duplicate. Just check out the earlier posting and determine if it helps you meet your objective.

Comment: Use `biblatex`: it has `maxnames`, `minnames` keys (3 by default), which may be different for bibliography and citations.