# natbib: setting max number of authors displayed in the references

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

How do I limit the maximum number of authors displayed in the references.

Example:

```
@ARTICLE{2013Natur.495...76P,    author = {{Pietrzy{\'n}ski}, G. and {Graczyk}, D. and {Gieren}, W. and     {Thompson}, I.~B. and {Pilecki}, B. and {Udalski}, A. and {Soszy{\'n}ski}, I. and   {Koz{\l}owski}, S. and {Konorski}, P. and {Suchomska}, K. and   {Bono}, G. and {Moroni}, P.~G.~P. and {Villanova}, S. and {Nardetto}, N. and    {Bresolin}, F. and {Kudritzki}, R.~P. and {Storm}, J. and {Gallenne}, A. and    {Smolec}, R. and {Minniti}, D. and {Kubiak}, M. and {Szyma{\'n}ski}, M.~K. and      {Poleski}, R. and {Wyrzykowski}, {\L}. and {Ulaczyk}, K. and    {Pietrukowicz}, P. and {G{\'o}rski}, M. and {Karczmarek}, P.    },
        title = "{An eclipsing-binary distance to the Large Magellanic Cloud accurate to two per cent}",   
        journal = {\nat}, archivePrefix = "arXiv",    
        eprint = {1303.2063},  
        primaryClass = "astro-ph.GA",
        year = 2013,
        month = mar,    volume = 495,
        pages = {76-79},
        doi = {10.1038/nature11878},
        adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2013Natur.495...76P}, 
        adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
```

Instead all of the authors showing up I would like to have something like:

```
G. Pietrzynski, et al., An eclipsing-binary distance to the Large Magellanic Cloud accurate to two per cent. Nature, 495:76–79, Mar. 2013. doi: 10.1038/nature11878.
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which bibliography style do you use?

Comment: Hi, I've tried plain, abbrvnat and unsrtnat.

Comment: Have you checked out the posting [BibTeX: How can I automatically reduce long author lists to “xxx et al.”?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26575/5001) The instructions given there apply to the `unsrt` bibliography style; however, they should also be applicable to `plain`, `plainnat`, and `unsrtnat`.

Comment: Good to know that the earlier posting worked for you. I'm going to propose to "close" your posting. Just to reassure you: There's nothing "wrong" with your posting; it's just that the previous posting provides the needed answer to the new posting.