# AGSM bibliography style sometimes doesn't abbreviate to "et al." for duplicate author+year

Tags: bibtex, citing, harvard-style

With BibTeX and the harvard/AGSM style, some references (from authors who have multiple papers per year) aren't abbreviated to "et al.", with the addition of `a`, `b`, et cetera. For example, with the code attached below, I get:

[image]

Only one paper is abbreviated to et al., the others not. Any idea why this is happening? The in-text references should be Basu et al. (2008a) and Basu et al. (2008b), which I believe AGSM should automatically do?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\cite{basu2008a, basu2008b, beare2006}

\bibliographystyle{agsm} 
\bibliography{references.bib}

\end{document}
```

With BibTeX file (`references.bib`):

```
@string{jam="J. Appl. Meteor."}
@string{ag="Acta Geop."}
@string{blm="Bound.-Layer Meteor."}

@article{basu2008a,
  author={Basu, S. and Vinuesa, J.-F. and Swift, A.},
  title={Dynamic {LES} modeling of a diurnal cycle},
  journal=jam,
  year={2008},
  volume={47},
  number={4},
  pages={1156-1174}
}

@article{basu2008b,
  author={Basu, S. and Holtslag, A. A. M. and Wiel, B. J. H. and Moene, A. F. and Steeneveld, G. J.},
  title={An inconvenient "truth" about using sensible heat flux as a surface boundary condition in models under stably stratified regimes},
  year={2008},
  journal=ag,
  volume={56},
  number={1},
  pages={88-99}
}

@ARTICLE{beare2006,
 author={Beare,R. J. and Macvean,M. K. and Holtslag,A. A. M. and Cuxart,J. and Esau,I. and Golaz,J. -. and Jimenez,M. A. and Khairoutdinov,M. and Kosovic,B. and Lewellen,D. and Lund,T. S. and Lundquist,J. K. and McCabe,A. and Moene,A. F. and Noh,Y. and Raasch,S. and Sullivan,P.},
 title={An intercomparison of large-eddy simulations of the stable boundary layer},
 journal=blm,
 year={2006},
 volume={118},
 number={2},
 pages={247-272}
}
```

Comment: It actually works correctly if both papers (`basu2008a`, `basu2008b`) have the exact same authors (result: `Basu et al. (2008a,b)`), or if one of the papers only has one author (result: `Basu et al. (2008), Basu (2008)`) or two authors (result; `Basu et al. (2008), Basu & Holtslag (2008)`). But as soon as it needs to add the `a` or `b`, something fails and the full list of authors is writting in-text

Comment: This link may be helpful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26575/bibtex-how-can-i-automatically-reduce-long-author-lists-to-xxx-et-al

Comment: meanwhile also posted on http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=27226

Comment: @Johannes_B - Done. :-) It turns out that this is a feature, not a bug... For sure, a very uncommon feature.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've come across an unusual -- and admittedly rather severely under-documented -- feature (not a bug...) of the `agsm` bibliography style. Suppose two bib items labelled, say, `AA` and `BB` each have one or more authors. Crucially, suppose the *total number* of authors differs -- e.g., let bibitem `AA` have 3 authors and bibitem `BB` have 5 authors -- and suppose further that `AA` and `BB` share the same first author (say, `XYZ`) *and* the same publication year (say, `2000`).

When this occurs -- as is the case in the example you've posted -- the `agsm` bibliography style does *not* set the citation call-outs as `XYZ et al (2000a)` and `XYZ et al. (2000b)`, respectively. Instead, it lists *all author names* for both publications.

I suppose this is a fail-safe way of avoiding any kind of confusion over whose publication might be cited as `XYZ et al. (2000a)`.

The only time when you do get the `FirstAuthor et al (year)` citation call-out pattern is if (a) the two publications have the same authors (and thus the same *number* of authors) as well as the same publication year *and* (b) there is no other three-or-more-author publication in the bibliography that features the same first author and publication year.

Again, this feature of the `agsm` style is both uncommon (to put it neutrally) and, unfortunately, quite obscure and under-documented. I wouldn't call it a bug, though. If you truly can't stand this feature, it's probably a good idea to start looking for an alternative bibliography style.

An MWE and screenshot:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{testagsm.bib}
@article{1,
  author = "XYZ", title = "x", journal= "y", year = 2000}
@article{2,
  author = "XYZ and B", title = "x", journal= "y", year = 2000}
@article{3a,
  author = "XYZ and B and C", title = "x1", journal = "y", year = 2000}
@article{3b,
  author = "XYZ and B and C", title = "x2", journal = "y", year = 2000}
@article{4,
  author = "XYZ and BB and CC and DD", title = "x", journal= "y", year = 2000}
@article{5,
  author = "XYZ and BBB and CCC and DDD and EEE", title = "x", journal= "y", year = 2000}
@article{x1,
  author = "A and B and C", title = "D1", journal = "E1", 
  year = 3001, volume = 1, number = 2, pages = "3-4"}
@article{x2,
  author = "A and B and C", title = "D2", journal = "E2", 
  year = 3001, volume = 5, number = 6, pages = "7-8"}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib,har2nat}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % just for this example

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\obeylines
\citet{1}
\citet{2}
\citet{3a}, \citet{3b}
\citet{4}
\citet{5}

\medskip
\citet{x1}, \citet{x2}
\endgroup

\bibliography{testagsm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, that's indeed a very strange "feature" :) But awesome, thanks for looking into it. After a quick test, `apalike` seems to do what I want, so I'll give that a try.

Comment: @Bart - Thanks for letting me know that you found this answer useful. About the `apalike` bibliography style: It's been around, virtually unchanged, since 1988. As such, it doesn't know what to do with (and hence ignores) fields such as `url`, `eid`, `issn`, etc. If such fields might be important for your thesis, and especially if your bibliography has to be formatted according to *current* (not 1988...) APA guidelines, you may want to look into using the much newer (and more feature-rich) [apacite](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/apacite/) package and bibliography style.

Comment: @Mico, again thanks...! The DOI's etc. were indeed missing, using `apacite` fixed that.

Comment: I know this is a very old question. But I am having the same issue using the AGU journal template in overleaf. The template however already uses `apacite` Any help is appreciated. More details and link to example in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/607871/agu-template-doesnt-abbreviate-with-et-al-for-duplicate-author-year).

Answer (score 0):

It is not a useful "feature" at all in any scientific writing I have seen.  I have the problem where I have the same group of authors who published several works in one year. The workaround I use is to also change the `year={}` field in my `reference.bib` file to read "2008a", "2008b" and so on.  Using the example above it would look like this:

```
@article{basu2008a,
  author={Basu, S. and Vinuesa, J.-F. and Swift, A.},
  title={Something},
  journal=jam,
  year={2008a},
  volume={47},
  number={4},
  pages={1156-1174}
}

@article{basu2008b,
  author={Basu, S. and Vinuesa, J.-F. and Swift, A.},
  title={Something else},
  year={2008b},
  journal=ag,
  volume={56},
  number={1},
  pages={88-99}
}
```

And so on ... then running BibTeX I get "Basu (2008ab)"  as expected.

Comment: But then you manually add `year={2008a}`, `year={2008b}`, etc., and what if you later remove (lets say) the one with `2008a`? You manually have to update other references; isn't that what a reference manager should do for you?

Comment: P.s.: what do you mean with `Basu (2008ab)`? That should never happen?

Comment: You are correct - I should have written "Basu et al. (2008a,b)"

Comment: If I just use `year = {2008},` in your `.bib` examples and add them to Mico's MWE I get the output "Basu et al. (2008a,b)" which seems really sensible. It goes against the spirit of BibTeX to add the `a` and `b` in the `year` field manually, since that letter might change or disappear when you add or remove other references.

Answer (score 0):

By the way: I've made an interesting finding. If you are writing your authors in the .bib file twice into brackets it's also going to name all authors for the \citep{}.

Example:
[...]
author = {[Sheng, Steve and Holbrook, Mandy and Kumaraguru, Ponnurangam and Cranor, Lorrie Faith and Downs, Julie}},
[...]

For me this resulted in naming all authors in the citation.