# modify the agsm.bst

Tags: harvard-style

I am using LaTeX with the article document class. The Bibtex bibliography style that I am using is agsm, part of the Harvard family of bibliography styles.

My article entry is

```
@Article{Bozzola2018,
    author  = {Bozzola, Martina and Massetti, Emanuele and Mendelsohn, Robert and Capitanio, Fabian},
    title   = {A Ricardian analysis of the impact of climate change on Italian agriculture},
    journal = {European Review of Agricultural Economics},
    year    = {2018},
    volume  = {45},
    number  = {1},
    pages   = {57-79},
    issn    = {0165-1587},
    doi     = {10.1093/erae/jbx023},
    type    = {Journal Article},
 }
```

If I cite Bozzola et al. (2018), then under *agsm* style, it would be as below in the reference list.

```
   Bozzola, M., Massetti, E., Mendelsohn, R. and Capitanio, F. (2018),
       ‘A ricardian analysis of the impact of climate change on Italian agriculture’, 
        European Review of Agricultural Economics 45(1), 57–79
```

Which part of the *agsm.bst* can I modify to obtain the outcome as

```
   Bozzola, M., E. Massetti, R. Mendelsohn, and F. Capitanio (2018),
       ‘A ricardian analysis of the impact of climate change on Italian agriculture’, 
        European Review of Agricultural Economics 45(1), 57–79 ?
```

Comment: Instead of hacking an existing bib style, especially a quirky one such as `agsm`, it would be much more efficient if you familiarized yourself with the `makebst` utility, which is part of the [custom-bib](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) package. The `makebst` utility lets users create highly customized bibliography style files from scratch. (In case you doubt my claim that `agsm` is quirky, do please check out the posting [AGSM bibliography style sometimes doesn't abbreviate to “et al.” for duplicate author+year](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297271/5001).)

Comment: Off-topic: The words "Ricardian" and "Italian" should be encased in curly braces, so that they won't get converted to all-lowercase lettering by a BibTeX bibliography style that practices [English-language] "sentence style".

Comment: Thanks for two comments. @Mico, actually I am writting research proposal and must follow "Harvard-ISS" style as the link following: https://www.eur.nl/sites/corporate/files/2017-10/ISS%20Referencing%20Guide%202017-18%20%5Bv.%202%20August%202017%5D.pdf I amnot familiar with BibTex, just starting, and see that the "agsm" style to some extent similar to my uni's requirement. At this moment I am studying how to use Bibulous. But the urgent case now, I think I utilise the agsm  :-)

Comment: It's a common misunderstanding that in order to "follow Harvard-ISS style", one must use an existing bibliography style (such as `agsm`) from the `harvard` family of styles. This is simply not the case. Happily, the `makebst` utility lets users create a bst file that satisfies each and every formatting requirement of the "Harvard-ISS" style -- and much more rapidly and robustly so than if users take the route of adapting (hacking!) an existing but quirky style such as `agsm`. Observing that the "agsm style [is] to some exten[t] similar to my uni's requirement" isn't saying much, really.

Comment: Consider use `biblatex` and `biber`. Probably you can fix all style requirement easily via biblatex package options without making a  .bst file, and maybe only using a predefined Harvard style for biblatex. I not testead any of these but seem that  [biblatex-bath](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-bath) package or [ecobiblatex](https://ctan.org/pkg/ecobiblatex) could be what you are looking for. Without biblatex, maybe [bath-bst](https://ctan.org/pkg/) can help.

Comment: Thanks Mico! I am going to forward to biblatex. No pain no gain :-)

Comment: @VũVõ - I'm very glad I was able to convince you to drop the project of modifying the `agsm` bibliography style.

Comment: @Mico - I approached LaTex 10 years ago, just use it. Not understand well how it works behind. It is also true for the Bibtex. I haven't updated much on how many packages can format the bibliography, and think that only Bibtex can do this work. :-) just follow the old route :-) Thanks again!