# natbib and agsm - citation call-outs to pieces with same first author & same year

Tags: citing, natbib, harvard-style

I'm using the `natbib` package with `agsm` bibliography style.

I have two references which have the same first author and which were published in the same year. Both references have more than 10 authors.

Let's call them `Smith2018a` and `Smith2018b`.

When I do `\citep{Smith2018a}` it lists every single author (similarly for Smith2018b).

I would like to edit the `agsm.bst` file so that instead it outputs something like: `(Smith et al. 2018a)`.

Does anyone know which bit of the `agsm.bst` file I need to edit and what I need to change it to?

Many thanks!

Comment: Your problem is just a sorting problem. You named them Smith2018a and Smith2018b, but this has nothing to do with the output of `\citep` command and the output in the references section. If you look carefully the (Smith et al 2018b) of the `\citep` command is refer to the correct item. So, there is no bug... If you just looking for a way to sort the entries your way please edit your question to make it clear

Comment: Did you see the posting [AGSM bibliography style sometimes doesn't abbreviate to “et al.” for duplicate author+year](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297271/5001)? The output behavior you've encountered is very much a design feature of the `agsm` and `dcu` bibliography styles. If you don't like this behavior, you're probably best off switching to a different, less-funky bibliography style.

Comment: @koleygr - Actually, the `agsm` bibliography style's way of displaying the names of authors in a citation call-out is quite different from most other authoryear-type styles.

Comment: So I'm aware that it's not a bug and I only called it a "feature/bug" in jest... I would like to stick with agsm but edit the agsm.bst file to make it output as I would like. Any suggestions in this direction?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal `bib` file for testing?

Comment: To achieve your overall objective, you could edit the functions `format.lab.names.abbr`, `format.lab.names.full`, `make.full.label`, and `make.abbr.label` in the file `agsm.bst`. Alternatively, you could run the [makebst](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib?lang=en) utility to create a bst file from scratch which (a) satisfies all of the your formatting requirements and (b) works perfectly with the `natbib` citation management package. BTW, the `har2nat` package should be loaded in order to make `agsm` work fully with `natbib`. I recommend the `makebst` route.