# Don't want citations to include all authors rather than et al

Tags: citing, natbib

Yet more problems are happening with my citations :(

I am writing my thesis in overleaf and I have collected my references from Mendeley in a BibTeX file which has been uploaded to overleaf. I am using the natbib package and agsm style.

Two of the citations are being weird with me and the citation includes all of the authors, rather than abbreviating it to et al. The rest of the citations are behaving, just these two. I can sometimes manage to get it saying et al, but it will inevitably return to listing all the authors. These references have been exported in the same way as the others so I don't understand what is wrong with them. Please can you help?

```
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib} 
\usepackage{har2nat}
```

```
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References} 
\bibliographystyle{agsm} 
\bibliography{library.bib}
```

```
@article{Rowe1970,
abstract = {}
author = {Rowe, Wallace P and Murphy, Frederick A and Bergold, Gernot H and Casals, Jordi and Hotchin, John and Johnson, Karl M and Lehmann-Grube, Fritz and Mims, Cedric A and Traub, Eric and Webb, Patricia A},
doi = {10.1128/JVI.5.5.651-652.1970},
file = {:Users/amelia13/Downloads/Journal of Virology-1970-Rowe-651.full.pdf:pdf},
issn = {0022-538X},
journal = {Journal of Virology},
number = {5},
pages = {651--652},
title = {{Arenoviruses: Proposed Name for a Newly Defined Virus Group}},
volume = {5},
year = {1970}
}

@article{Rowe1970SerologicalVirus,
abstract = {},
author = {Rowe, Wallace P and Pugh, Wendell E and Webb, Patricia A and Peters, Clarence J},
doi = {10.1128/jvi.5.3.289-292.1970},
file = {:Users/amelia13/Downloads/jvirol00291-0015.pdf:pdf},
issn = {0022-538X},
journal = {Journal of Virology},
number = {3},
pages = {289--292},
title = {{Serological Relationship of the Tacaribe Complex of Viruses to Lymphocytic Choriomeningitis Virus}},
volume = {5},
year = {1970}
}

@article{Radoshitzky2015,
abstract = {},
author = {Radoshitzky, Sheli R and B{\`{a}}o, Yīm{\'{i}}ng and Buchmeier, Michael J and Charrel, R{\'{e}}mi N and Clawson, Anna N and Clegg, Christopher S and DeRisi, Joseph L and Emonet, S{\'{e}}bastien and Gonzalez, Jean Paul and Kuhn, Jens H and Lukashevich, Igor S and Peters, Clarence J and Romanowski, Victor and Salvato, Maria S and Stenglein, Mark D and de la Torre, Juan C.arlos},
doi = {10.1007/s00705-015-2418-y},
file = {:Users/amelia13/Downloads/Radoshitzky2015{\_}Article{\_}PastPresentAndFutureOfArenavir.pdf:pdf},
issn = {14328798},
journal = {Archives of virology},
number = {7},
pages = {1851--1874},
title = {{Past, present, and future of arenavirus taxonomy}},
volume = {160},
year = {2015}
}
```

Example text

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4 paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib} 
\usepackage{har2nat} 

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

Example text \cite{Rowe1970}. Example text \cite{Rowe1970SerologicalVirus}. Example text \cite{Radoshitzky2015}


\renewcommand{\bibname}{References} 


\bibliographystyle{agsm} 
\bibliography{library.bib}
\end{document}
```

Also, as a side note, I've had some previous trouble with the bibliography when I was importing directly from Mendeley and making the BibTeX file has helped fix those problems - however when I am citing now, the \cite{} seems to remember all of the older suggestions and I was wondering if there is any way to make it only suggest the references that are in the current library.bib file? I've tried clearing the cache but it didn't do anything.

THANKS!
Amelia

Comment: cite doesn't "remember" anything it uses the generated bibliography in bbl file which you need to generate with bibtex after any change to your citations or the bib file. mostly overleaf will run bibtex for you when needed but you can always delete the bbl file to force it to be regenerated. You haven't provided any example document that allows anyone to see what output you are getting or test answers so it is hard to help.

Comment: is the agsm bibtex style that you are using compatible with natbib?

Comment: I didn't think cite would remember but like the above example the cite is Rowe1970SerologicalVirus and when I cite this, Rowe1970SerologicalVirusb also appears even though it isn't in the .bib file. How do I delete the bbl file? Also how do I provide an example document for you? And yes it appears to be compatible - someone else suggested it and it gives me the references in the way they should be presented according to the university

Comment: I have edited the question - is that the kind of example text you were after?

Comment: The `agsm` and `dcu` bibliography styles are both provided by the `harvard` citation management package, and they share a feature which, as far as I can tell, is unique to these two styles: if there are two multi-authored publications with the same first author, the citation call-outs will *not* employ an "et al"-type abbreviated citing mechanism *unless* the two author lists are identical. See [AGSM bibliography style sometimes doesn't abbreviate to “et al.” for duplicate author+year](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297271/5001) for more information.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - `agsm` and the other bib styles provided by the `harvard` package are almost fully compatible with `natbib`. Loading `har2nat` establishes full compatibility.

Comment: @Mico oh right, I understand why it's happening now then. I suppose there is nothing that I can do about it then if I want to keep this citation style... Thank you for your help!

Comment: I have managed to fix it by adding a or b to the year in the bib file! Thanks for helping, I wouldn't have known why it wasn't working if you hadn't! :)