# AGU template doesn't abbreviate with et al. for duplicate author-year

Tags: bibtex, citing, apa-style, apacite

I am having the same issue described in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297271/agsm-bibliography-style-sometimes-doesnt-abbreviate-to-et-al-for-duplicate-a) when using the AGU template on overleaf.
In the agujournal2019.cls file, however, the `\bibliographystyle` is already set to `apacite` (line 1091) as suggested in the question mentioned.

Anybody has this issue or an idea of how to deal with this?
I have created and shared [a project on overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/7647435596gmcydwgqvpfr) to show the issue and share the .cls file in question.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question has been long, but I hope my ideas here will help somehow. In my opinion, there are two things in your issue. First, you have two references that started with the same lead author (Basu) and same year (2008). To understand further, you might want to visit this [website](https://morningside.libguides.com/APA7/authors) for some information. One suggestion is to paraphrase the sentences that you are going to include these references to cite them differently in case you do not like the style mentioned in that site. Secondly, you might want to change `\cite` into `\shortcite` for 7th apa style, as it will help you to shorten many authors into 'et al.' (You can check by referencing them one by one)

Comment: Thanks for this. I had forgotten about asking this question. I ended up solving this "issue" by simply realising that this isn't actually a bug at all, but a feature of the AGU template I was using.

Comment: From [AGU's guide](https://www.agu.org/Publish-with-AGU/Publish/Author-Resources/Grammar-Style-Guide#referenceformat): If two or more references of more than three but less than six surnames with the same year, shorten to the same form (e.g., both Jones, Tuller, Park, & Wu, 2013, and Jones, Tuller, Park, Le Pinchon, & Johnson, 2013), shorten to cite the surnames of the first authors and of as many of the subsequent authors as necessary to distinguish the two references followed by a comma and “et al.”: Jones, Tuller, Park, and Wu (2013) and Jones, Tuller, Park, Le Pinchon, et al. (2013).