# How to find the unsrt.bst file

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I am sorry to post this probably very basic question, but I am having a hard time locating my unsrt.bst file as I want to edit it. I have read through a lot of questions in here, but in all of them it seems implied how you find the unsrt.bst file. Sometimes it is written that it is placed in Library/textmf/bibtex/bst, but I can't find any of those folders.

Comment: Please **never** change an original file! Copy it into your current directory, change the name , edit it and use it calling with the new name.  Try the command `kpsewhich unsrt.bst` on your terminal/console to find the current file ...

Comment: Of course, I wouldn't edit the original file. I just need it to get the code, so I can edit the thing I want to edit. Should I write that code in the texmaker programe or somewhere else, and do I write it in a blanc document? I don't understand what you mean by typing the command on my terminal/console. I am quite obviously new to LaTex.

Comment: Seems you are using only the graphical user interface of MAC.  The terminal or console means that you open a new window (please type terminal into your search function of MAC) where you can write commands. After pressing enter the typed command is excecuted. (Sorry, I do not have an MAC here and it is a long time ago I used one. I can't remember better ...)

Comment: Yes, I have only used the graphical user interface of my Mac until now. I did as you explained and got a root for the unsrt.bst file. However, I still can't locate the file. It says that it is under usr/local/texlive, but I can't find the texlive folder. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your last comment about the location for personal bst files I'm guessing you are using a Mac. Under TeX Live installed by MacTeX your personal tree's root is ~/Library/texmf and personal bst files should go into ~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bst or sub-folders of that folder. A couple of things you should know: ~/Library is the Library folder in your HOME folder; and, if you haven't done so already, YOU must create the set of nested folders texmf/bibtex/bst/... in ~/Library. To open ~/Library hold the Option key down while clicking on the Go menu in Finder; a new Library item, that opens ~/Library, will appear.

Comment: Okay, I did not understand that the ~/Library folder was on my computer, I thought it was supposed to be in a LaTex folder. I have created the set of nested folders now. However, I don't understand how to try the command, as @Kurt writes above. Is it in texmaker or somewhere else I need to type that code? Should it be in a blanc document? I am very new to LaTex.

Comment: You use Terminal to type the commands @Kurt mentions.

Comment: Alternatively, in Finder use Go->Go to Folder… (Shft-Cmd-G), enter /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/base/ in the space provided and press Return. That will open that folder. Then press and hold the Option key and drag the usrt.bst to your Desktop. Make sure you use the Option key so the system copies the file rather than moving the file. Then rename the copy and you can edit it in TeXShop or TeXmaker or any other text editor.

Comment: I have now followed the guidance in this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26575/bibtex-how-can-i-automatically-reduce-long-author-lists-to-xxx-et-al
Do any of you guys know where to save the new unsrt85.bst file? I have tried making the folders /Library/texmf/bibtex/bst and also tried making them under users/home/Library and saving my new bst file with no luck. LaTex says it can't open the style file, so I guess I must have placed it somewhere wrong.

Comment: I see that you saved it in /Library/texmf/bibtex/bst but the tree is supposed to start in ~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bst. Notice the leading ~ which stands for your HOME folder! I told you how to open that Library folder before.

Comment: I have tried saving it in my home folder. That was what I meant with the /Library. Didn't know that ~ means home. It doesn't work.

Comment: In Terminal please run the command `ls -al ~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bst` and let me know what it returns.

Comment: It says: ls:  ~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bst: No such file or directory
Under HOME I have found a folder called lib - could that be the library folder I am searching for? I can't make new folders in that folder for some reason.

Comment: If I put the new .bst file into the same folder as my LaTex document, it apparently works.

Comment: @Lea: I was afraid of that. You built the texmf tree in the wrong Library folder; you used the folder at the base of you Hard Drive rather than the one in your HOME folder. Please open the Library folder in your HOME folder by clicking on the Go menu in Finder and the pressing the Option key so a new Library item appears in that menu. Then build that texmf tree in that Library folder.