# How to not use the full fist name in IEEE spconf paper (abbreviated first name with bibtex)

Tags: bibtex, citing, ieee-style, ieeeconf

I'm trying to put the first name of the authors in the references, abbreviated. For example **John Smith** should become **J. Smith**. I was able to produce the problem even from official MLSP conference [template](http://mlsp2018.conwiz.dk/paper_submission.htm). Here is the minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mlspconf}

\title{How abbriviated first name appear in the references}
\name{John Doe} 

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
    The problem is apearing of full first name in the references
\end{abstract}
\begin{keywords}
    test first name
\end{keywords}


\section{Introduction}


This is a test \cite{Schr}. 

\bibliographystyle{IEEEbib}
\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

and here is the .bib tex:

```
@article{Schr,
    author = {Smith, John and Doe, George},
    title = {Test name abbriviations},
    journal = {Commun. ACM},
    issue_date = {May 2018},
    volume = {65},
    number = {4},
    month = apr,
    year = {2018},
    issn = {0002-1834},
    pages = {60--69},
    numpages = {11},
    publisher = {ACM},
    address = {New York, NY, USA},
}
```

*NOTE1*: I'm using bibtex and just in case, the [`IEEEbib.bst`](http://mlsp2018.conwiz.dk/files/IEEEbib.bst) and [`mlspconf.sty`](http://mlsp2018.conwiz.dk/files/mlspconf.sty) are available at [here](http://mlsp2018.conwiz.dk/paper_submission.htm)

Comment: Check this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/482291/113143

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for providing a link to the bst file. I suggest you proceed as follows.

- Make a copy of the file IEEEbib.bst and call the copy, say `IEEEbib-abbrev.bst`. (Don't edit an original file directly.)
- Open the file `IEEEbib-abbrev.bst` in a text editor. (The editor you use for your tex files will do fine.)
- In the file `IEEEbib-abbrev.bst`, locate the function `format.names` and, in this function, the line

  ```
      { s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
  ```

  Change `{ff~}` to `{f. }`.
- Next, locate the function `format.crossref.editor` and, in this function, the line

  ```
      { editor #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
  ```

  Change `{ff }` to `{f. }`.

  In case you haven't already guessed what's going on: `ff` is short for "full first name", and `f.` is short for "first name abbreviated to first initial, followed by a dot (period, full stop)".
- Save the file `IEEEbib-abbrev.bst`, either in the directory where the main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{IEEEbib}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{IEEEbib-abbrev}
  ```

  and perform a complete recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more -- to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!