# How to show at most three authors for any bibliographic entry

Tags: bibtex

If a bibliographic entry has *more than three* authors, I want to have only the first three authors' names written out, plus "et. al".

I found out that to achieve this I have to change the .bst file and therein the "format.names" function. I found this other [site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26575/bibtex-how-to-reduce-long-author-lists-to-firstauthor-et-al) where basically my question is answered. However I don't know why this solution does not work in my case and therefore the following post:

To be more precise my original format.names function looks like:

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
    { namesleft #1 >
        { ", " * t * }
        { numnames #2 >
        { "," * }
        'skip$
          if$
          t "others" =
        { " {\em et~al.}" * }
        { string.and * t * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
```

and the new one is

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 
  nameptr #1 >
     {
      nameptr #3
      #1 + =
      numnames #5
      > and
        { "\bibinfo{person}{\bibinfo{person}{others}}" 't :=
          #1 'namesleft := }
        'skip$
      if$
      namesleft #1 >
}
```

With the new format.names function I get many errors when I apply BibTeX:

```
The top-level auxiliary file: thesis_main.aux
The style file: utphys_custom_threeAuthors.bst
function is an unknown function---line 415 of file utphys_custom_threeAuthors.bst
format.authors is an unknown function---line 415 of file utphys_custom_threeAuthors.bst
Curse you, wizard, before you recurse me:
function format.names is illegal in its own definition
---line 418 of file utphys_custom_threeAuthors.bst
```

Unfortunately I do not understand the language in which the .bst file is written and I might have a stupid mistake. It would be awesome if you could help me.

Comment: If you use `biblatex` it is as simple as  loading it with options `[maxnames=3,minnames=3]`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is the original, i.e, unmodified version of `utphys.bst` available online?

Comment: Should the string "et al." (please, please not "et. al."!) be rendered in italics?

Comment: @Mico it is not available online, but I can put in in the post if you want?

Comment: @Mico not necessarily. It can also be non italic

Comment: @jojo123456 - I've looked over the [most-upvoted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26582/5001) -- the first solution, not the one labelled "Addendum May 2019" -- in the link you posted. To put it politely, you appear to have botched the instructions given in that answer. To be sure, I can see no reason why the answer I provided nearly 8 years ago shouldn't work for `utphys.bst` as well. The only thing you need to adapt is to replace `numnames #5` with `numnames #3`, since you wish to apply truncation whenever there are more than 3 authors. Please do give it another try.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I made it work with biblatex now!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem is solved in the comments.