# Limit the number of authors in bibliography when using elsarticle

Tags: elsarticle

I prepared my article with **elsarticle** class using

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
```

The requirement from the journal is that bibliography entries should contain at most 6 authors; the rest should be written as "et al.". What would be the best way to accomplish this? In my current setup there is no limit to the number of authors shown.

Comment: Well, according to the documentation `elsarticle` by default uses `natbib`, so you might find this answer useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26582/118712

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Indeed it seems that replacing the format.names function in a .bst file such as model1-num-names.bst (belonging to the elsarticle bundle), as suggested by in the answer you provided, works.

Comment: Just make sure, you find a solution that will work with the way your file will be compiled by the journal you are submitting to. In my experience changing the template or its .bst file may not be a good solution. However, if the journal explicitely asks for this and this is their template, there should be an easy solution actually. Maybe it is best to confirm with the editorial office before submitting.