# Reference Style of a Template and Change This Style?

Tags: biblatex, formatting, templates

I have found a template for a paper (https://academic.oup.com/comjnl/pages/Manuscript_Preparation_Submission; scroll to: **Latex 2E And The COMJNL.CLS File**), but I am having problems compiling my *.bib in the style that the template requires. The *.bbl is build like:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{gelenbe06}
Gelenbe, E. (2006) Analysis of automated auctions.
\newblock {\em ISCIS 2006, LNCS 4263},  Istanbul, Turkey,  1-3 November,  pp.
  1--12. Springer Verlag, Berlin.

\end{thebibliography}{99}
```

Which reference style is it? I think, I have to change the referencing style at TeXstudio that the code at the file COMJNL.CLS works. I use TeXstudio and JabRef.

How I have to manipulate the following code (?)

```
% need to be explicit with `References' for \uppercase'ing
\def\thebibliography#1{\section*{References}\small\list
 {[\arabic{enumi}]}{\labelsep 0.5em%
\hyphenpenalty=50\itemsep=-1pt
 \settowidth\labelwidth{[#1]}\leftmargin\labelwidth
 \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
 \usecounter{enumi}}
 \def\newblock{\hskip .14em plus .38em minus -.1em}
 \sloppy
 \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}
\let\endthebibliography=\endlist

\def\@cite#1#2{[{#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi}]}
\def\@biblabel#1{[#1]}

\let\origthebibliography\thebibliography
\def\thebibliography#1{\origthebibliography{\hbox to 1em{\hss}}}
```

at the COMJNL.CLS that I can use other commands/reference styles like:

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, natbib=true,maxcitenames=1,  uniquelist=false, backend=biber]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`.zip` file](https://static.primary.prod.gcms.the-infra.com/static/All+Journals/comjnl/Document+Library/comjnl-latexprep2_Aug2021.zip?node=e6e3b11398afaca8e0e0&version=439998:953f03ad473a86888d57) available at https://academic.oup.com/comjnl/pages/Manuscript_Preparation_Submission#Latex contains a `sample.tex` file with working bibliography setup

```
\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{compj}
\bibliography{ModellingBidders}
```

The `.zip` file also includes the BibTeX style file `compj.bst` that is referenced there.

This *strongly* suggests you should not and cannot use `biblatex` for a submission (`biblatex` is incompatible with classical BibTeX sytles). Just use BibTeX with `compj` as suggested by the sample document.

Unfortunately, there is an *extremely* weird bug in the version of `compj.bst` (`This is a version of cj.bst v1.1 2003-08-18` modified with [BibTeX: How to reduce long author lists to "Firstauthor et al."?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26575/)) that is currently included in the `.zip`: It says `http://format.date` when it should say `format.date`. So open the file and search-and-replace `http://format.date` with `format.date` (normally I would say that you should also rename the file and add a short comment at the top of the file to explain the change, but since the file is not administered by your TeX distribution and you probably have to download the `.zip` again for a new submission to be sure you get the current version of the files that is probably less relevant).

With that change

```
\documentclass{comjnl}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Lorem \cite{article-full}

\bibliographystyle{compj}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

will produce the desired output assuming `comjnl.cls` and `compj.bst` are in the same directory as the `.tex` file.

Comment: Thank you very much. It more or less worked. The bibliography is now translated and inserted into the paper. However, this applies to all sources in my *.bib file, even if only a part of it is referenced. Do you have any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: @Kopi That will be the `\nocite{*}`. That command adds all entries in the `.bib` file to the bibliography regardless of whether or not these entries were cited in the text. Remove the `\nocite{*}` and recompile the document. Then you should only see entries that you actually cited in the bibliography. (As in the example document I posted.)

Comment: Thank you. That works.