# With biblatex, replace all authors after a specific author with 'et al.'

Tags: biblatex

My LaTeX CV ends with a list of my publications. Some of those have 50+ authors and I'd like to reduce this list by replacing some of the author names by 'et al.'. For now I have limited the author list to 5 with the .bst edit from this response

[BibTeX: How to reduce long author lists to "Firstauthor et al."?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26575/bibtex-how-to-reduce-long-author-lists-to-firstauthor-et-al)

However I would rather put the 'et al.' after my own name in the author list instead of after the fifth author, so that it is always clear that my name is included in the list. I suppose this is possible because it is also possible to format a specific name differently than others (for example [Make specific author bold using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73136/make-specific-author-bold-using-biblatex)) but I could not figure out how to do it.

**Update #1:**
Moewe's answer of using biblatex-publist was the right approach, but I had to customize the options to (1) fit with my previous citation style which was not based on biblatex-publist's base style of authoryear and (2) split the bibliography in publications and communications, which I was doing with multibib before but it is not compatible with biblatex-publist. This is a MWE working for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\publistbasestyle{trad-abbrv}
\usepackage[bibstyle=publist, plauthorhandling=highlight, plsorting=none, plnumbering=local-descending, hlyear=false, marginyear=true, minnames=4, maxnames=7, isbn=false, url=false, pubstateextra=false]{biblatex}

\plauthorname{Elk}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname-publications.bib}
@book{elketal,
  author    = {Quinn Wong and Leonardo Bruce and Damari Leach
               and Emilee Berry and Miracle Stafford and Raquel Hammond
               and Madilyn Gregory and Amari Valdez and Amaris Carroll
               and Terry Monroe and Raymond Leach and Gunnar Koch
               and Anne Anne Elk and Anne Uthor},
  title     = {More Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1973},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname-communications.bib}
@unpublished{elkconf,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title         = {A new theory on Brontosauruses},
  note  =  {First controversial conference on the world around us, London, UK},
  year = {1972}
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\newrefsection[\jobname-publications]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title=Publications]

\newrefsection[\jobname-communications.bib]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title=Communications]
\end{document}
```

[image: A screenshot of the resulting bibliography, showing entries separated by year and between publications and communications, ordered by most recent first]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the specific job of a publication list for you CV you can use `biblatex-publist`. That style has the feature to highlight your name and can drop "unnecessary" name around it to ensure the entries don't get too long.

More customisation features can be found in [the `biblatex-publist` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-publist/biblatex-publist.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bibstyle=publist, plauthorhandling=highlight]{biblatex}

\plauthorname{Elk}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
@book{elketal,
  author    = {Quinn Wong and Leonardo Bruce and Damari Leach
               and Emilee Berry and Miracle Stafford and Raquel Hammond
               and Madilyn Gregory and Amari Valdez and Amaris Carroll
               and Terry Monroe and Raymond Leach and Gunnar Koch
               and Anne Anne Elk and Anne Uthor},
  title     = {More Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1973},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [1] Wong, Quinn, [...], Elk, Anne Anne, et al. 1973. More Theory on Brontosauruses. London: Monthy & Co. [2] Elk, Anne. 1972. A Theory on Brontosauruses. London: Monthy & Co.]