# Customizing bibliography format and resolving expression issues in publication title -- LaTeX

Tags: bibliographies, bibliographystyle

I'm currently working on my LaTeX document and facing some challenges with customizing the bibliography format. I have a .tex file with the following packages and a corresponding biblio.bib file containing my bibliography.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report} 

\usepackage{tabularx,amsmath,boxedminipage,graphicx}

\usepackage[margin=1in,letterpaper]{geometry} 

\usepackage[final]{hyperref} %adds hyp

\usepackage{cite}

\linespread{1.8}

\usepackage{algpseudocode} %to write algorithms

\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{bigints}

\usepackage{mathptmx} %Font style 

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{relsize}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2009}{\,}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{authblk} %to include multiple authors

\usepackage{amssymb} %to include symbols for R, C etc

\usepackage{tcolorbox} %to make coloured boxes

\usepackage{multicol} %to make multiple columns of text

\usepackage{bm} %To use boldface in maer links inside the generated pdf file

\usepackage{array}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,       %false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=red,          %color of internal links
    citecolor=red,        %color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,      %color of file links
    urlcolor=blue         
}

\xpatchcmd{\algorithmic}{\itemsep\z@}{\itemsep=2ex plus2pt}{}{}

\makeatother

\usepackage{exscale}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,% make the links colored
}


\usepackage{datetime}

\newdateformat{monthyeardate}{\monthname[\THEMONTH], \THEYEAR}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}

\def\blankpage{%
      \clearpage%
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
      \null%
      \clearpage}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
.
carbon isotopes paper \cite{John}.
.


\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

biblio.bib sample:

```
@article{John,
title = {Z = 6 has isotopes 12,14C}, `//even if I change it to "Z = 6 has isotopes $^{12,14}$C," results remains same`
journal = {Nature Physics},
volume = {790},
pages = {251-256},
year = {2019},
issn = {0370-2693},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/024},
url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/0014},
author = {J. Smith and A. Smith and B. Smith and C. Smith and D. Smith and E. Smith},

}
```

I want to print the bibliography in a specific format where it begins with " [1] J. Smith et al., followed by the title of the paper, and then the journal, year, etc.
Additionally, I'd like the bibliography list to maintain chronological order based on the citations in the main text.

Currently, I've been attempting to achieve this with the above style.

However, the results are not as expected. The expressions in the titles seem to be messed up. For example, if the title is "Z = 6 has isotopes $^{12,14}$C" after applying \bibliographystyle{unsrt}, it appears as "z = 6 has isotopes 12,14c."

Any tips on getting my bibliography to behave and fixing those expression hiccups? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What happens if you change `Z = 6` and `$^{12,14}$C` to `{Z} = 6` and `$^{12,14}\mathrm{C}$`, respectively, in the bib file and rerun BibTeX, followed by two more LaTeX runs?

Comment: @Mico Thanks; that works. Any recommendations on the first author et al. instead of all the names and regarding the problem related to the chronology of the citations?

Comment: Do stop loading the `cite` package twice. See the posting [BibTeX: How to reduce long author lists to "Firstauthor et al."?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26575/5001) on how to reduce the number of authors shown in the bib entries. [Shameless self-citation alert!] The main answer truncates the author list if the author list has 5 or more members. To handle the case of not showing more than 2 surnames, please see one of the comments below the main answer.

Comment: Thanks again, @Mico. I wanted only the first author et al., so I modified the .bst accordingly.