# How to restrict number of cited authors in \citet or \citeasnoun

Tags: natbib, author-number

This is actually a follow up question to [How do I truncate the author list and substitute et al.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24460/how-do-i-truncate-the-author-list-and-substitute-et-al/128567#128567) where I was advised to open a new question.

I would like to use \citet or \citeasnoun apparently depending on packages natbib or havard in my text. I have several citation where I get a larger number of authors printet in text which is annoying. I was hoping that this could be easily solved and found the old thread where I was advised to use natbib. Unfortunately natbib somehow does not work as descirbed and tex still prints Ghosh, Levin, Macmillan, and Wright (2004) instead of Gosh et al. (2004). I occasionally have the same problem.

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    %\usepackage{harvard}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    %\usepackage{ngerman}
    \usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{natbib}

    \begin{document}
    %\bibliographystyle{econometrica}
    blabla \citet{ghosh2004gold}

    \bibliography{goldhedge}
    \end{document}
```

Does somehow not work for me. The bibtex entry should be.

```
@ARTICLE{ghosh2004gold,
      author = {Dipak Ghosh and Eric J Levin and Peter Macmillan and Robert E Wright
},
      title = {Gold as an inflation hedge?},
      journal = {Studies in Economics and Finance},
      year = {2004},
      volume = {22},
      pages = {1--25},
      number = {1},
      publisher = {Emerald Group Publishing Limited}
    }
```

Thats actually somethign that has been bugging me forever.. Any ideas why it does not work for me?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it was enough to change from econometric to chicago

```
     \bibliographystyle{chicago}
```