# Bibliography with chapters by different authors in a book

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing

I'm currently writing a paper where I need to reference a a chapter within a book.

So, for example I have a book, which is written by several authors and have a title.
Inside the book, there are different other authors in different chapters. So for example I have:

- Book name: Book Title
- Authors of the book: Juan, D. and Dean, J. and Stark, T.
- Chapter title: Title of the chapter
- Author of the chapter: DiCaprio, L.
- Pages: 150-170

And then of course there are some publisher stuff and such.

My question is then: How should I be writing this in LaTeX ? I'm using BibLaTeX, and the book/article references given by:

```
@article{Xarticle,
author    = "",
title     = "",
journal   = "",
%volume   = "",
%number   = "",
%pages    = "",
year      = "XXXX",
%month    = "",
%note     = "",
}
```

and

```
@book{Xbook,
author    = "",
title     = "",
publisher = "",
%volume   = "",
%number   = "",
%series   = "",
%address  = "",
%edition  = "",
year      = "XXXX",
%month    = "",
%note     = "",
}
```

So yeah, I actually needs 2 titles, and 2 authors, at least in my head. But I can't figure out how to go about this ?

So any help would grateful.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
So actually, in one of my articles, it says: "This chapter should be cited as"

Le Treut, H., R. Somerville, U. Cubasch, Y. Ding, C. Mauritzen, A. Mokssit, T. Peterson and M. Prather, 2007: Historical Overview of
Climate Change. In: Climate Change 2007: The Physical Science Basis. Contribution of Working Group I to the Fourth Assessment Report
of the Intergovernmental Panel on Climate Change [Solomon, S., D. Qin, M. Manning, Z. Chen, M. Marquis, K.B. Averyt, M. Tignor and
H.L. Miller (eds.)]. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, United Kingdom and New York, NY, USA.

So the main authors of the chapter, IN the book which different authors.

Can this be done in LaTeX ?

Comment: Here's a very similar question: [How to cite a chapter in a book with BibTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60843/5872)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite a perfect match, but I think the closest in `@incollection`, according to the [wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Standard_templates):

> @incollection
>
> - A section of a book having its own title.
>
>   - Required fields: author, title, booktitle, publisher, year.
>   - Optional fields: editor, volume/number, series, type, chapter, pages, address, edition, month, note.

The only issue is that the field for the person with overall responsibility is `editor` (and this is sometimes obvious in the bibliography, depending on the style), however books of this type are often indexed under the editor anyway. Actually for your example, that's perfect -- "(Eds.)" appears as I would expect.

Comment: That actually seems like it would work.
But now it only writes out the first author, followed by et al. ?
Is there any way that I could just write out ALL author names, at least in the bibliography ?

Comment: Some of the answers [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5662/bibtex-automatic-replacement-of-4-authors-with-et-al) may help, if you can't or won't use biblatex (like me for example, due to journal requirements):

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Too long for a comment to Chris H.'s answer</sup>

Book chapters should be `@inbook` or `@incollection` in BibTeX. Normally, as seems to be the case here, we reference *collections'* chapters, which are self-contained texts within a collection (although in book form). Chris H. is right that this entry should be of the `@incollection`type.

<sup>(BTW, this is only valid for BibTeX, since `biblatex` uses a very different approach here)</sup>

So the entry should look something like this:

```bibtex
@incollection{LeTreut-etal,
  author = {Le Treut, H. and
      R. Somerville and
      U. Cubasch and
      Y. Ding and
      C. Mauritze and
      A. Mokssit and
      T. Peterson and
      M. Prather},
  title = {2007: Historical Overview of Climate Change},
  booktitle = {Climate Change 2007: The Physical Science Basis. 
      Contribution of Working Group I to the Fourth Assessment Report 
      of the Intergovernmental Panel on Climate Change},
  editor = {Solomon, S. and
      D. Qin and
      M. Manning and
      Z. Chen and
      M. Marquis and
      K. B. Averyt and
      M. Tignor  and
      H.L. Miller},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
  address = {Cambridge, United Kingdom and New York, NY, USA},
}
```

Now, the way that you want the authors' names to be shown depends entirely on the *style* file you're working with. For a visual list of examples, see [*BibTeX Style Examples*](http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/software/latex/showbst.html).

Here's a MWE with `alpha` style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{LeTreut-etal,
  author = {Le Treut, H. and
      R. Somerville and
      U. Cubasch and
      Y. Ding and
      C. Mauritze and
      A. Mokssit and
      T. Peterson and
      M. Prather},
  title = {2007: Historical Overview of Climate Change},
  booktitle = {Climate Change 2007: The Physical Science Basis. 
      Contribution of Working Group I to the Fourth Assessment Report 
      of the Intergovernmental Panel on Climate Change},
  editor = {Solomon, S. and
      D. Qin and
      M. Manning and
      Z. Chen and
      M. Marquis and
      K. B. Averyt and
      M. Tignor  and
      H.L. Miller},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
  address = {Cambridge, United Kingdom and New York, NY, USA},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cite{LeTreut-etal}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\end{document}
```

> [image: alpha example]