# Strategy for managing multiple Bibtex files

Tags: bibtex

My work involves producing various documents with citations (e.g., journal articles, conference presentations, reports, etc.).
Publications cite references, and references can be specific to a given publication, or to a set of publications built around a study, or a set of studies, or a research program. A reference may even cross-over into multiple research programs.

I'm a big fan of the DRY Principle (i.e., Don't Repeat Yourself).
However, I'm also a big fan of making projects portable.

Satisfying both principles seemingly leads to a conflict in relation to bibtex files.

- Is it a good strategy to have a single master bibtex file for all projects and adopt some automated copying system whereby each publication gets a copy of the overall bibtex file (or a subset)?
- Or is it better just to have lots of little publication specific bibtex files?
- Or is there some other system that people find works best?
- What tools can assist?

Comment: http://ctan.org/pkg/bibtools

Comment: as pointed out below by Charles Stewart, this question overlaps with http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1380/how-to-avoid-bibtex-error-message-repeated-entry-for-an-entry-appearing-in-seve

Comment: See `bibexport` as in answer for [Creating .bib file containing only the cited references of a bigger .bib file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41821/creating-bib-file-containing-only-the-cited-references-of-a-bigger-bib-file?lq=1).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I just keep everything in one big BibTeX database and use the search function in [JabRef](http://jabref.sf.net).

If I really need to give away a subset of the references to a co-worker (and don't want to send the whole file), I generate a new, smaller .bib-File using the "New subdatabase based on AUX file" from the Tools menu in JabRef.

But ultimately, you'll just adopt a system that works best for you. [Mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com/) has been suggested, I've also heard good things about [CiteUlike](http://www.citeulike.org/).

Comment: Same here. BibDesk for Mac OS X (which I use) also has a "Select Publications from .aux File" feature.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a big fan of JabRef. And it's good to know that others work this way. I'm leaning towards automating the process of reference extraction, perhaps as mentioned in a separate answer using something like the bibexport script

Comment: BibDesk is a great piece of software. Unfortunatly I *must* use Windows at work, where all the reference-TeXing happens. At home on my Mac I mostly just write letters...

Comment: ++1 for JabRef!

Answer (score 8):

I have one master BibTeX file, which is versioned by itself in a Git repository. When writing a paper (each is also versioned as a separate Git repository), I include the master .bib file as a Git [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). It puts the master .bib file as a subdirectory of my paper 'project'.

This way I have one copy of my bibliography, and my projects are portable as requested in the question.

Furthermore, Git submodule points to a specific version of the master BibTeX file. Therefore my paper always uses the original .bib file state, even if I have updated it in the master repository since (e.g. even changed reference keys). Similarly I could have paper-specific changes to the master file via branching.

The approach would also work with multiple authors/bibliographies - just include multiple submodules.

This is the general idea. To spare an overlong answer here, [my blog has more details of the solution](http://andrius.velykis.lt/2012/06/master-bibtex-file-git-submodules/) with sample repository structure to illustrate.

Comment: This seems like a very nice idea. However, sooner then later one will run into problems when trying to implement this when having coauthors. See the discussion following the linked post.

Answer (score 3):

Nbibtex.  See [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1380/how-to-avoid-bibtex-error-message-repeated-entry-for-an-entry-appearing-in-seve/1389#1389) to the *how to avoid bibtex error message “repeated entry” for an entry appearing in several bibtex files?* question.

Answer (score 3):

I use [Mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com/) to store and organize my articles, then use separate internal libraries for each project.  Each library can then be exported to a bibtex file.  It also has the added benefit of a shortcut (CTRL-K to get a latex entry copied to the clipboard).

Comment: I think you meant clipboard instead of keyboard `:)` I've raised an edit proposal (I can't edit directly yet).

Comment: FYI Mendeley does not do biblatex.

Answer (score 2):

While JabRef allows for exporting references from a `bib` file based on an `aux` file, I like to have an automated build based on a `makefile`.

Following on from Habi's response, I did a little Googling and found `bibexport`.
It seems well suited to maintaining a centralised bib file, and automating the extraction of references based on citations in a document.

- http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/utils/bibexport/

**Update:** 
I'm quickly discovering there are many tools for automating the above process.

- http://ctan.org/pkg/bibtools
- http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/utils/bibtool/

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a good strategy to have a single master bibtex file for all projects and adopt some automated copying system whereby each publication gets a copy of the overall bibtex file (or a subset)? Or is it better just to have lots of little publication specific bibtex files?

When I start a new draft, I use a script to create a template that includes all my bibtex files, to which I link using symmetric links. I can see the advantage of having one large bib file, but the downside for me is that I'll probably spend a lot of time looking for the right reference in that file, whereas small, topic-based files allow me to work quicker.

> What tools can assist?

[Mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com/) not only allows you to organise, tag, ... your papers, but also to create collections and synchronize whole, exported .bib files with them. I believe this could be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use a single master bibfile (using aux2bib from bibtools to make subsets if needed).  The trouble is that I now write papers together with other people, and we don't share a master bibfile (or even a common format for bibtex keys).

So I currently have lots of papers in different Subversion repositories, each with its own set of bibfiles.  One thing that helps is a script I wrote for grepping all the bibfiles and finding the distinct entries.  So when I need a new entry for a project, I can see if I already have it somewhere else.

This is certainly suboptimal.  Maybe Mendeley is the solution but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

A reasonable approach would be to have some central database system and export work-specific .bib files for each article, report etc. Ideally, this system would allow to save work-specific literature selections (to be able to modify and re-export them easily when the tex document evolves).

Until now I did not find such a system.

Comment: Problem is, that once you branch from the central file the new `bib` file gets life of it own, and it may evolve independently from the central file. One related problem I can think of, is how to merge back the branched files?