# Best script for automatically copying references from a centralised bib file based on aux file

Tags: bibtex, auxiliary-files

In a previous [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6393/strategy-for-managing-multiple-bibtex-files) I asked about best practices when managing multiple bibtex files.

One strategy involves having a single centralised bibtex file.
Then, citations in a particular article are imported based on an aux file.

While it is possible to do the importing manually using JabRef, 
I would like to be able to automate the process as part of a makefile.

My question:

- Which of the various scripts that are available would be best for this purpose?
- Which of them work on Windows?
- Are there are any other general tips related to automating the extraction of citations for a particular article from a centralised bibtex database?

The ones that I've seen mentioned:

- [bibtools](http://ctan.org/pkg/bibtools): particularly [aux2bib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/utils/bibtools/aux2bib) and `subset`
- [bibexport](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/utils/bibexport/)
- [bibtool](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/utils/bibtool/)
- [bibextract](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/utils/bibextract/)

**Update (7/12/2010):**
The reason that I want to do this is that I want to upload all files to a self-contained repository. I'd also like others to be able to re-use components of the repository (e.g., the bib file). For example someone might want to get a copy of all the references in my paper and add them to their bibtex database.

Comment: Jeromy: Very timely. I had been discussing just this with friends.  I keep copying too many reference from one master to numerous different 'per-project' bib files and would rather keep them linked so that *one* update in the master gets reflected in all.  I'd also prefer scripts over big mean Java programs (hence no Jabref) or cloud services that could pack up and leave.  I may try `bibtools`.

Comment: @Dirk. Thanks. `bibtools` might be the first one I try also.

Answer (score 9):

(**This *is* an answer**)

Here's a script that I used to use for managing BibTeX `.bib` files before I learnt how to Do Things Properly!  The only bit it doesn't do is extract the references from the `.aux` file.  But that wouldn't be very hard to do.  The vast majority of this script is about setting up the configuration.  The actual meat of it is in the last loop which slurps through a `.bib` file and looks for the appropriate entries.  The reason that that loop is so short is because someone else has already written a `Text::BibTeX` perl module, whereupon the rest is window dressing.  If this is the sort of thing that you are after, then it would be really easy to adapt it to (a) search through the `.aux` file to find the references and (b) not bother with all the other things that I used it to do (such as automatically download references from the arXiv).

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
#use Getopt::Long qw(:config auto_help bundling);
use Getopt::Long qw(:config bundling);
use Pod::Usage;
use Text::BibTeX;
use LWP::MediaTypes qw(guess_media_type);

# This is the only variables that should need customising

my $conffile = "$ENV{HOME}/.refsrc";

###
# Nothing below here should need customisation
###

my (
    $bibbase,
    $hostname,
    $docbase,
    $reffile,
    $lynx,
    $arxivdir,
    $ext,
    $authors,
    $refs,
    $reduced,
    $silent,
    $titles,
    $append,
    $view,
    $show,
    $help,
    $man,
    $gpl,
    $bibfile,
    $entry,
    $output
    );

my @reffiles;
my %mime;
my %values;
my @shrt;
my %tests;

@shrt = ("title","author");

%tests = (
    "authors" => [0, sub {
    my ($e,$b) = @_;
    my @a;
    if ($$e->exists('author')) {
        @a = $$e->split('author');
    } elsif ($$e->exists('editor')) {
        @a = $$e->split('editor');
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
    for (my $j = 0; $j <= $#$b; $j++) {
        for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#a; $i++) {
        return 1 if $a[$i] =~ /$$b[$j]/i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
    }],
    "refs" => [0, sub {
    my ($e,$r) = @_;
    for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#$r; $i++) {
        return 1 if ($$e->key =~ /^$$r[$i]$/);
    }
    return 0;
    }],
    "titles" => [0, sub {
    my ($e,$t) = @_;
    for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#$t; $i++) {
        return 1 if ($$e->get('title') =~ /$$t[$i]/i);
    }
    return 0;
    }]
    );

# Default display routine
$output = sub {
    my ($e) = @_;
    if ($append) {
    $$e->set_key($append . $$e->key);
    }
    $$e->print();
};

GetOptions (
# List of things to look for in the author/editor entries
    "a|authors=s@" => sub {
    my ($a, $b) = @_;
    push @{$values{"authors"}}, split(",",$b);
    $tests{"authors"}[0] = 1;
    },
# List of things to look for in the reference entries, array?
    "e|refs=s@" =>  sub {
    my ($a, $b) = @_;
    push @{$values{"refs"}}, split(",",$b);
    $tests{"refs"}[0] = 1;
    },
# Whether to print the full entry or a basic summary
    "r|reduced" => sub {
    $output = sub {
        my ($e) = @_;
        print $append if ($append);
        print $$e->key . "\n";
        for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#shrt; $i++) {
        $$e->exists("$shrt[$i]") and print $$e->get("$shrt[$i]") and print "\n";
        }
    }
    },
# Whether to produce any output, or just an exit code
    "s|silent" => sub {
    $output = sub {
        exit 1;
    }
    },
# List of things to look for in the title entries
    "t|title=s@" => sub {
    my ($a, $b) = @_;
    push @{$values{"titles"}}, split(",",$b);
    $tests{"titles"}[0] = 1;
    },
# Modify references by appending this string
    "u|append=s" => \$append,
# Try to display an appropriate file
    "v|view" => sub {
    $output = sub {
        my ($e) = @_;
        my ($mi,$ex);
# if the key has three digits, then it's highly likely to be an arXiv ref
        my $u = ($entry->key =~ /\d\d\d/ ? "" : chr(95));
        my @p = glob("$docbase/*/" . $entry->key . "$u*");
        if (!@p) {
        print "Couldn't find a file for: " . $entry->key . "\n";
        }
        for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#p; $i++) {
        $mi = guess_media_type($p[$i]);
        if (exists($mime{$mi})) {
            ($ex = $mime{$mi}) =~ s/%s/$p[$i]/;
            if (!fork) {
            exec $ex
                or die "Couldn't execute $ex";
            }

        } else {
            print "Couldn't find a program to view: " . $entry->key . " file: $p[$i] mimetype: $mi\n";
        }
        }
    }
    },
# Try to locate an appropriate file
    "x|locate" => sub {
    $output = sub {
        my ($e) = @_;
# if the key has three digits, then it's highly likely to be an arXiv ref
        my $u = ($entry->key =~ /\d\d\d/ ? "" : chr(95));
        my @p = glob("$docbase/*/" . $entry->key . "$u*");
        if (!@p) {
        print "Couldn't find a file for: " . $entry->key . "\n";
        }
        for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#p; $i++) {
        print $p[$i];
        }
    }
    },
    "h|?|help" => \$help,
    "m|man" => \$man,
    "gpl" => \$gpl
    ) or pod2usage(2);

pod2usage(-exitval => 1, -verbose => 0) if $help;
pod2usage(-verbose => 2 ) if $man;
exec 'perldoc perlgpl' if $gpl;

if (!-e $conffile) {
    print STDERR "$conffile does not exist.\n";
    exit 1;
}

open (CONF, $conffile)
    or die "Couldn't open $conffile for reading.\n";

while (<CONF>) {
# Set configuration variables; currently only bibbase and docbase
    if (/=/) {
    /(\w*)\s*=\s*(.*?)\s*$/;
    my $s = "\$$1 = \"$2\"";
    eval($s);
    $@ and die $@;
    next;
    }

# Stuff of the form 'name.bib' is a bibtex file to parse
    if (/(\w*\.bib)/) {
    push @reffiles, $1;
    next;
    }

# Stuff of the form 'mimetype; application' tells us how to view
# certain files

    if (/^\s*([a-z]*\/[a-z-]*);\s*(.*)/) {
    $mime{$1} = $2;
    }
}

die "$bibbase is not a directory.\n" unless -d $bibbase;
die "$docbase is not a directory.\n" unless -d $docbase;


# Loop over the bibtex reference files looking for the entries

for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#reffiles; $i++) {
    if (! -f "$bibbase/$reffiles[$i]" ) {
    print STDERR "$reffiles[$i] is not a regular file.\n";
    next;
    }

    $bibfile = new Text::BibTeX::File "$bibbase/$reffiles[$i]";

  ENTRY: while ($entry = new Text::BibTeX::Entry $bibfile) {
      if (!$entry->parse_ok) {
      print STDERR "Error in input, skipping entry\n";
      next;
      }

      next unless ($entry->metatype eq BTE_REGULAR);

      foreach my $t (keys %tests) {
      next unless $tests{$t}[0];
      if (&{$tests{$t}[1]}(\$entry,$values{$t})) {
          &$output(\$entry);
          next ENTRY;
      }
      }

  }

    $bibfile->close;
}
```

Configuration file example:

```
bibbase = /home/astacey/texmf/bibtex/bib
docbase = /home/astacey/docs/MathsPapers
hostname = front.math.ucdavis.edu
reffile = /home/astacey/texmf/bibtex/bib/arxiv.bib
lynx = /bin/lynx
arxivdir = /home/astacey/docs/MathsPapers/arXiv/
ext = .pdf


arxiv arxiv.bib
article articles.bib
book books.bib
other misc.bib

application/pdf; /usr/bin/xpdf %s
application/postscript; /usr/bin/gv %s
application/x-dvi; /usr/bin/xdvi %s

book          -> book
article       -> article
booklet       -> book
conference    -> book
inbook        -> article
incollection  -> article
inproceedings -> article
manual        -> book
mastersthesis -> other
misc          -> other
phdthesis     -> other
proceedings   -> book
techreport    -> article
unpublished   -> other
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this at a UNIX shell, with some usually true assumptions about the structure of `.aux` and `.bib` files, using mostly `awk`.  This is less robust than a maintained program, but it is more flexible if you have any skill with shell programming, and probably less work for a couple of hundred Bibtex items than evaluating a complex piece of software.  First, you can get the cited keys from the `.aux` file using the shell function, which accepts the filenames of multiple `.aux` files as arguments:

```
getbibkeys () { awk -F{ '$1=="\\bibcite" { print substr($2,0,length($2)-1)}' "$@"; }
```

You can then fetch from bibfiles, with the first argument the Bibtex key and the following arguments the `.bib` files to look in:

```
fetchbibitem () { 
    key="$1"; shift; 
    awk -v key="$key" 'BEGIN {RS="@"} $1~".*{" key "," {print "@" $0}' "$@";
}
```

A simple read-while loop using the above gives the desired functionality:

```
getbibkeys $AUXFILE | while read -r key; do fetchbibitem "$key" $BIBFILE; done
```

(I've tested the two shell functions, but not the read-while loop).

Be clear: these will break on some uncoventional .bib files, even though they are accepted by Bibtex.

Answer (score 4):

(**This is not an answer**: it is an extended comment, but the comment box got too restrictive.)

I'm probably being a bit dense, but I don't see the point in what you are trying to do.  Let me describe what I see, so that you can say what's wrong in this picture.

1. There is a central `.bib` file containing just about every reference you (or your coauthors) have ever even thought of.
2. You (and your various coauthors) have a variety of documents that refer to stuff in this central `.bib` file.
3. You want a program that looks in the `.aux` file for a list of references, then goes to this `.bib` file, extracts the relevant entries, and then puts them in a local `.bib` file ready for insertion in to the document.

Is that right?

If so, let me change two letters in the above.  Let me change the *last* `.bib` to `.bbl`.  So now it reads:

1. There is a central `.bib` file containing just about every reference you (or your coauthors) have ever even thought of.
2. You (and your various coauthors) have a variety of documents that refer to stuff in this central `.bib` file.
3. You want a program that looks in the `.aux` file for a list of references, then goes to this `.bib` file, extracts the relevant entries, and then puts them in a local `.bbl` file ready for insertion in to the document.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't that *exactly* what BibTeX does?

What do you gain by having the local `.bib` file?  The only thing that I can see is that it allows you to change the bibliography style without needing a trip to the central repository again.  But how often do you do that?  Is it so often that recreating the `.bbl` file is so painfully time consuming?  Surely, you do that once when you submit it to a journal (or if you're like me, once *each* time you submit it to a journal).

If you want to be able to make changes to the local file, then I don't see that that's so much more difficult with a `.bbl` file than a `.bib` file; and in both cases you have problems with your changes surviving a recreation of the file so I can't see that that is the issue.

Comment: Perhaps some journals want a `bib` file, rather than a `bbl` file?

Comment: @Seamus: not even the arxiv is happy with a `.bib` file.  My (limited) experience is that journals really want everything folded in to one single file (I've had to do that for a 6-tex and 3-style document; not pretty).

Comment: @Andrew I'm still learning the details of bibtex; so forgive me if my assumptions are incorrect. My aim is to upload my source files (sweave, tex, images, bib, etc.) to a repository. I want the repository to be self-contained. I'd also like others to be able to re-use components of the repository (e.g., the bib file). For example someone might want to get a copy of all the references in my paper and add them to their bibtex database. `bib` files seem to make this easier than `bbl` files.

Comment: @Jeromy: That's slightly different because now you've added the step of importing references to someone else's BibTeX database.  In that case, I strongly recommend that you use a proper bibliographic database system with import/export facilities which has the capability of importing and exporting to bibtex.  There are many such.  Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1380 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1612/86

Comment: @Andrew I currently use JabRef to manage my references. As mentioned I want to share my bib file as part of my repository because others may want to reuse the references. When I say others, I'm not thinking of actual collaborators on a paper. Rather, I'm thinking of consumers of my research who might find it useful to get a quick copy of all references in a paper. I guess it's up to them how they import this bib file into their own system.

Comment: @Jeromy: I don't know anything about JabRef; I use a PHP+MySQL set up called RefBase.  What I can do with that is create a "group" for a paper so anyone wanting the references can click on the group associated to the paper to bring up all the references, whereupon they can export them in whatever format they like.  This is just "point and click" on their behalf, which seems much easier than trying to figure out how to dig out references from a file.

Answer (score 3):

There is also the bib2bib program that comes with bibtex2html:
http://www.lri.fr/~filliatr/bibtex2html/

A windows installer is up for download.

Comment: bibtex2html is even included in MiKTeX, in contrast to bibtools

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why exactly this would be necessary but here's a working python solution.  It will get screwed up if you have anything on your entries' first lines other than `@<type>{key,` and on their last lines something other than `}` but you shouldn't be doing that anyway.

Save to exportcitations.py, `chmod +x exportcitations.py` and then just run `./exportcitations.py doc.aux bigbibtexfile.bib > actualcitedpapers.bib`

Like I said, you probably don't need this (you really just want to copy `doc.bbl` into your `tex` file.  But if you want it, here it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from sys import argv 

try: 
    citems=[i[9:].strip().split("}")[0] for i in open(argv[1]).xreadlines() if i[:9]==r"\bibcite{"]
    printme=False
    for row in open(argv[2]).xreadlines():
        if row[0]==r"@":
            if row.strip().split("{")[1].strip(',') in citems:
                printme=True
        if printme:
            print(row.rstrip())
        if row.strip() == "}":
            printme=False
except:
    print("You need to input a valid aux file for arg1 and bib file for arg2.\n")
```